# how to get default database name of system DSN of windows in java

Tags: java, dsn

```
     DatabaseMetaData data = connection.getMetaData();
     resultSet =  data.getCatalogs();
     while (resultSet.next()) {
      System.out.println(resultSet.getString("TABLE_CAT"));
    }
```

above code gives me name  of all the database of the sql server but i need only default database that configured in DSN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
    ResultSet resultSet1 = statement.executeQuery("select db_name()");
    while (resultSet1.next()) {
        System.out.println(resultSet1.getString(1));
    }
```